# Electric field for a partially inserted dielectric slab in a parallel plate capacitor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, dielectric

I’m working on a problem that I think I solved incorrectly yet I don’t know where my mistake is.
Suppose we partially insert a dielectric slab (with constant $\kappa$) inside a parallel plate capacitor (in a vacuum) where the area of both plates is $A$. Let $A_D$ be the area that the dielectric occupies and let $A_v$ be the area the vacuum occupies $\Rightarrow A = A_v + A_D$.

Now using Gauss Law in both cases we get that
$$D_v = \frac{q}{(A - A_D)}, \ D_D = \frac{q}{A_D}$$

Then $D_v = \varepsilon_0 E_v$ and $D_D = \kappa \varepsilon_0 E_D$ so we know the electric field for both cases. As we can see if $A_D = 0$ and $A_D = A$ we get what we should for $E_v$ and $E_D$ respectively.

Yet I think my answer is wrong, we should expect the electric field to be zero for $E_v$ and $E_D$ when $A_D = A$ and $A_D = 0$ respectively because in those cases either the dielectric is completely inside the capacitor or it is completely outside the capacitor, however this doesn’t happen and they both diverge to infinity in their respective cases. What am I missing here?

Comment: t might help you to stand back and consider the arrangement as two capacitors in parallel. The potential difference across each capacitor would be the same but the charge on each capacitor would not be the same.  So what is $q$ in your equations?

Comment: $q$ is the magnitude of the charge in each plate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes, it is good to fall back on the basics. The plates are equipotential surfaces. Therefore, the electric field between them is still uniform and identical for both regions. However, what's different is the electric displacement and the surface charge densities of the two regions. The charges are no longer uniformly distributed on the plates. We can use Gauss' Law to find the electric displacements and verify that they result in the same electric field for both regions. $$\oint \mathbf{D} \cdot d \mathbf{a} = Q_f$$

Comment: I arrived at this conclusion with the assumption that the capacitor is fed up with constant potential. Yet what I quite don’t understand is that for the potential to be constant the charge must change in the dielectric’s region (because the dielectric weakens the electric field). However because our plates are metallic they are equipotential surfaces so the charge must remain the same throughout the plates (otherwise there would be a potential difference within the plate). Isn’t this a contradiciton? (Of course the most probable thing is that my reasoning is wrong).

Comment: @RMor - there can be no potential difference within a conductor. The charges move to match the polarisation charges in the dielectric.

Comment: But if the charges move to match the polarization charge from the dielectric then there would be more charge on the dielectric’s side than there would be on the vacuum’s side because the capacitor is fed up with constant potential. How can there be more charge on one side of the plate yet at the same time be equipotential?

Comment: @R.Mor: The potential at a conductor can be broken into the superposition of the potentials due to itself and others, which can be written as $V_{total} = V_{self} + V_{others}$. For the section without the dielectric, $V_{others} = 0$, so $V_{total} = V_{self}$. But, the dielectric creates an opposite potential difference across it, so $V_{others} \neq 0$, which requires more charge on the plates to make the $V_{total}$ equal, so the values of $V_{self}$ are not equal for the 2 sections. Therefore, since $V_{self}$ is not equal, the charges, which are the sources of it, cannot be equal.

Comment: @user7777777 that clears it up. Thank you very much.